# Convert string values of associate array to integer

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array as follows.

I need to convert the values as integer

```
array:17 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "c" => "gmail"
    "co" => "12"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "c" => "dddd"
    "co" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "c" => "mmmmm"
    "co" => "2"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "c" => "dsf"
    "co" => "2"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "c" => "aaaa"
    "co" => "1"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    "c" => "bbbb"
    "co" => "1"
  ]
  6 => array:2 [
    "c" => "ccc"
    "co" => "1"
  ]
  7 => array:2 [
    "c" => "yopmail"
    "co" => "1"
  ]
  8 => array:2 [
    "c" => "yahoo"
    "co" => "1"
  ]
]
```

I need to convert all values of the key `co` to integer ,where currently they are string.

Is this is the way to use the foreach,which didn't give me correct output

```
 foreach($getDashboardDetails as $getDashboardDetails)
    {
        $getDashboardDetails['co']=(int)$getDashboardDetails['co'];
    }
```

Hope Someone can help

Comment: why you didnt use `foreach` ?

Comment: you can use casting for 'co' in the array by (int) co

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself, or made some research on possible solutions? Please post your efforts

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you can't use the same var name for the foreach item. Rename the variable after 'as' and use the renamed variable inside.

Comment: @RenéBeneš Tried..No change..:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `for` loop is more what are you looking for as you want to change the initial array.

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($getDashboardDetails)-1;$i++) {
    $getDashboardDetails[$i]["co"] = (int)$getDashboardDetails[$i]["co"];
    $i++;
}
```

Or you can use `foreach` with a key-value pair on both dimensions, but I don't find it neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you on your way(assuming `$getDashboardDetails` is the source array):

```
foreach($getDashboardDetails as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        if ($key1 === "co") {
            $getDashboardDetails[$key][$key1] = (int)$getDashboardDetails[$key][$key1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get it, your `foreach` is in incorrect foam.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($getDashboardDetails as $key=>$value)
{
    $new_array[$key]=array("c"=>$value['c'], "co"=>(int)$value['co']);
}
```

Now you have `$new_array` with expected results.